# How can i make formula simplest CNF?

Tags: logic, computer-science, equivalence-relations

I tried to simplify the formula ,but i am not sure if it is correct or not. If it is not correct how can i simplify the below formula?

> ((p ∨ r) ∧ (q ∨ r) ∧ (p ∨ s) ∧ (q ∨ s))

I thought that, if i combine RHS and LHS

RHS = (p ∨ r) ∧ (q ∨ r)
LHS = (p ∨ s) ∧ (q ∨ s)

RHS = (p∧q)vr

LHS = (p∧q)vs

RHS ∧ LHS = ((p∧q)vr)∧(p∧q)vs))

= (p∧q)v(r∧s)

is this correct simplify? Other question is, Is my solution equivalent formula in CNF?

Comment: you got it.  That's correct.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Looks good. Due to the top-level "and" conjunctions it's easier on a Karnaugh map to check the excluded options.

Comment: What you started with was/is in conjunctive normal form.  What you end with, however, is in **Disjunctive Normal Form** Your steps are correct, but they take you to a simplified DNF, not a simplified CNF.

Comment: @amWhy so it is converted CNF to DNF?

Comment: M.J. Exactly!${}{}{}$

Comment: Is that what you were seeking, M.J.: CNF to DNF?, or were you simply trying to work with the original CNF to arrive at a simpler CNF?

Comment: @amWhy Oh no i want to find simpler CNF.

Comment: M.J. What you start with is the most simplified in CNF.  What you obtain is the simplest form of DNF.

Comment: oh i want to have CNF ,but accidentaly show the DNF form.